# "... como no fuera llevar otro río nuevo" ¿qué tipo de oración es?

Tags: sintaxis

¿Qué tipo de oración es "como no fuera llevar otro río nuevo" en el siguiente fragmento?:

> Nunca se tomó el trabajo de pensarlo y cuando se dio cuenta de la verdad ya no había nada que hacer, **como no fuera llevar otro río
>   nuevo**.

Comment: La pregunta es "qué tipo de oración"? Se responde con Bimembre o Unimembre. Aquí hay un sujeto tácito El/Ella. Oración bimembre. Si se refiere al significado de lo que está entre comillas es otra pregunta y tiene que ver bastante más con la interpretación (que es difícil dado que es una única oración y no es una metáfora "común")

Comment: … sí, la pregunta es ¿q tipo de oración subordinada es la oración que he puesto en negrita? (ya sabes, hay oraciones condicionales, causales, consecutivas, comparativas etc.)

Answer (score 3):

La oración está indicando que «llevar otro río nuevo» es la única opción alternativa a no hacer nada; o lo que viene a ser equivalente, de no «llevar otro río nuevo», no se podría hacer nada.

Quizás es un poco obscura por ser una construcción negativa, y porque el «como no fuera», aunque bello, es poco habitual.

A mi entender, se podría sustituir bastante bien el «como no fuera + *inf*» por un «a no ser que + *subj*».

> ...ya no había nada que hacer, a no ser que llevase otro río nuevo.

Es decir, una subordinada adverbial, concretamente [condicional](http://www.gramaticas.net/2012/07/ejemplos-de-subordinada-adverbial_27.html).